# Go installer behavior on Mac: PATH modification vs symlink

Tags: macos, go, path, installation

In my experience, most software for OS X that installs cli components installs to `/usr/local/` and then creates symbolic links to executables in `/usr/local/bin/`, as not to modify my `$PATH`. However, the Go installer differs in approach by creating a new entry in `/etc/paths.d/` for [`path_helper`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html) to read and then modify my `$PATH`. Can someone please explain the thinking behind this design decision? Is it more common on Linux to have a lot of path additions instead of symbolic links to executables in an existing directory?

I'd love to get a better understanding of why this choice. I have never seen another software take this approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the design decisions made in creating the installer for a software development toolchain, unrelated to any act of software development itself.

Comment: @Adrian Where do you suggest is the appropriate site to post? There is not a SE site for Go and this has the largest Go community by posts. Don't vote to close, but vote to migrate.

Comment: This isn't a Go question. You could rephrase it to replace "Go" with "some program" and it would have no impact. I would vote to migrate if I thought there was an appropriate SE site for this question, but I'm not sure there is.

Comment: The right place to ask this would probably be at [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts)

Comment: @TehSphinX I already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread](http://www.kilala.nl/Sysadmin/index.php?id=934), the `path_helper` ([source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-179/path_helper/path_helper.c)) is:

> because automatic software installation (and what's more important UNinstallation) is much easier this way. Many Linux distros switch to `.d` directories for many configuration files (Apache 2.0 was AFAIK the first program to support this kind of stuff) because it makes administration much easier.

The [Uninstall Go section](https://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall) does mention:

> If you installed Go with the [Mac OS X package](https://golang.org/doc/install#osx) then you should remove the `/etc/paths.d/go` file.

Those [files in `/etc/paths.d` are processed in order](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/xquartz-dev/2015-November/003910.html) (so you can manage `PATH` order as opposed to symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`).

Note that `path_helper` is only called by login shells, not by non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using an answer; I don't have enough reputation points to comment. ((which seems backwards to me))

@jsejksn says "I have never seen another software take this approach."

My /etc/paths.d contains entries for Xquartz, CrossPack-AVR, aria2c and go. From reading google'd articles about /etc/paths.d, I see that ImageMagik also adds an entry to /etc/paths.d.

I'd guess that it's an easy way to let users run binaries without having to mess around with amending the PATH in their own profile scripts, or lose track of symlinks, or whatever.

Maybe sym-links is more of a Gnu thing, while /etc/paths.d is more of a BSD thing?

Personally, I like it.